# Вопрос по MySQL like

Tags: mysql, like

Есть таблица с полем которое содержит перечисление idшников из другой таблицы,
Я понимаю что бы выбрать по этому полю я должен использовать LIKE, однако к примеру такая ситуация

id | materialid

1 | 1,2,5,16

2 | 5,3,12,17

Как быть в ситуации если пользователь ищет с материалом 2?
По факту получается используя патерн %2% запрос вернет обе строчки, как быть что бы возвращалась только первая?

Comment: Я могу понять, когда LIKE используют для поиска по строкам, но в примере используется int, а не string -- и более того, это явно внешний ключ к id материала. Приведите таблицы к третьей нормальной форме и забудьте про LIKE.

Comment: Что вам мешает написать `'%,2,%'?